# Sylpheed is still in the menu

Tags: menu, sylpheed

I installed Lubuntu 14.04 and Thunderbird so I uninstalled Sylpheed, but it is still in the main menu!

Nothing happens when clicking the menu item, but anyway I would like to have it removed.

I have tried to install Sylpheed again - still only 1 "Sylpheed menu item" - and then uninstall it again - but it still remains in the menu.

How can I remove it from the menu ?

Comment: Try using `sudo apt-get purge sylpheed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Sylpheed activator:

```
rm -f ~/.local/share/applications/sylpheed.desktop
sudo rm -f /usr/share/applications/sylpheed.desktop
```